# Concatenate custom picklist field with number field

Tags: formula, editor

'Location' is the field name and is field type = picklist
'Account_ID' is the field name and is field type = number

I want to concatenate these two.

My formula is
TEXT(Location) & "-" & TEXT(Account_ID)

I am getting error message as follows:
Error: Field Location may not be used in this type of formula

What is wrong with my formula? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`Location` and `Account_ID` looks like they are custom field. We refer custom field as their API names and they end up with __c

Thus if we follow that convention, your formula will be

```
TEXT(Location__c) & "-" & TEXT(Account_ID__c)
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. As you suggested, I updated the formula using API name instead of  field name...

Comment: And then I encountered more syntax errors. The system asked me to add double quotation marks " and then asked me to remove TEXT(). Finally, I had not syntax errors when I used the following:                                            ("Location__c") & "-" & ("Account_ID__c").        But, the data are not concatenating. When I check the records after implementing, I see a blank field.

Comment: What syntax error you encountered? `TEXT(Location__c) & "-" & TEXT(Account_ID__c)` literally works for me

Comment: Good question - here is the Error that I get when I use the formula you suggested:  Error: Field Location__c may not be used in this type of formula
Use formula syntax: Enclose text and picklist value API names in double quotes : ("the_text"), include numbers without quotes : (25), show percentages as decimals: (0.10), and express date calculations in the standard format: (Today() + 7), To reference a field from a Custom Metadata type record use: $CustomMetadata.Type__mdt.RecordAPIName.Field__c

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I problem was that my field type was wrong. I had to delete the field and make a brand new FORMULA FIELD, with type = text. After I did that, then this formula worked: TEXT(Location__c) & "-" & TEXT(Account_ID__c)